# Getting current time in php

Tags: php, sql, time

I m trying to grab current time when a user enters a record, I can grab the time and date, they are all fine except the hour, I'm assuming its a different time zone? is their anyway of doing this if so i would love to know my code is below

```
<?php
$FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
$LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
$Postcode= $_POST['Postcode'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$Rating = $_POST['Rating'];
$Comment = $_POST['Comment'];
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

try
{
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pizza_shop', $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO guest(GuestID, FirstName, LastName, PostcodeFK, Email, Date, Rating,Comment) VALUES ('', '$FirstName', '$LastName', '$Postcode', '$Email', '$Date', '$Rating', '$Comment')";
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "<script>alert('Record Added.');location.href='@customers.html'</script>";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "<script>alert('Error'); location.href='@add_customer.html'</script>";
}

$conn = null;
```

Comment: What timezone you need ??

Comment: use date_default_timezone_set('your time zone'); at the top of your page

Comment: This might help with what you're trying to do [Setting PHP Timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: your script gets the server time. so i don't think its connected to the timezone. what is your output?

Comment: @Manadh GMT/UTC + 08:00 hour

Comment: To avoid confusion, it is always preferable to store times in UTC and only change them when displaying. Otherwise DST changes may cause some issues, especially if you are calculating something based on the timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try like this,

```
<?php 
 date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); // Change your TZ
 $date= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> date_default_timezone_set — Sets the default timezone used by all
>   date/time functions in a script.

if it is ok , then

```
 date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); 
 $date= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```